# How to set/get protobuf's extension field in Go?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I am a Go language developer. Our team chose to use protocol buffers to transform data.
I chose this protobuf package:  https://github.com/golang/protobuf.
However, this package has no method to handle the `extensions` field in a protocol buffer. I have only found this code in the class file generated by protoc:

```
var E_Height = &proto.ExtensionDesc{
    ExtendedType:  (*Person)(nil),
    ExtensionType: (*int32)(nil),
    Field:         110,
    Name:          "eg.Height",
    Tag:           "varint,110,opt",
}

func init() {
    proto.RegisterExtension(E_Height)
}
```

So, how can I set/get the `extensions` field in Go?

Comment: Take a look at the source for the extension handling code in the protobuf library [here](https://github.com/golang/protobuf/blob/master/proto/extensions.go). I get the impression that they don't want you to access the `extensions` field directly, but you can get and set extensions using API functions like `GetExtensions`.

Comment: There's `GetExtension`, `GetExtensions` and `SetExtention`. Do you need to do something that those functions can't handle?

Answer (score 2):

Getting the extension...

```
yourExtendedEvent := &path_to_your_events.Person{}
err := proto.Unmarshal(yourBytes, yourExtendedEvent)
if err != nil {
    // handle error case
}
extendedEvent, extendedError := proto.GetExtension(
    yourExtendedEvent,
    path_to_your_events.E_Height,
)
...
```

Setting the extension...

```
yourExtendedEvent := &path_to_your_events.Person{
    Field1: proto.Uint64(1),
    Field2: proto.String("foo"),
}

height := &path_to_your_events.Height {
    Field1: proto.Int64(120),
}

err := proto.SetExtension(
    yourExtendedEvent,
    path_to_your_events.E_Height,
    height,
)

if err != nil {
    // handle error case
}
```

**EDIT**

Actually, if I am reading it right, your extension is just a single field (an int32) so I don't know that you actually have a `Height` type.  If not, it might be more like

```
height := proto.Int32(120)
```

And then you set the same way with height as a single field rather than as a distinct proto type.

This line

```
ExtensionType: (*int32)(nil),
```

Makes me think it will be a single field, whereas our extensions look more like

```
ExtensionType: (*SomeOtherType)(nil),
```

This is a good resource
[TestExtensionsRoundTrip](https://github.com/golang/protobuf/blob/master/proto/extensions_test.go#L96)

Comment: Hi @sberry what if you have a large number of extensions? is there a way to get the extension type by a string?  meaning Person have `ex_type`

Answer (score 1):

From: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/go-generated#extensions

> For example, given the following definition:
>
> ```
> extend Foo {
>   optional int32 singular_int32 = 1;
>   repeated bytes repeated_string = 2;
>   optional Bar repeated_message = 3;
> }
> ```
>
> Extension values may be accessed as:
>
> ```
> m := &somepb.Foo{}
> proto.SetExtension(m, extpb.E_SingularInt32, int32(1))
> proto.SetExtension(m, extpb.E_RepeatedString, []string{"a", "b", "c"})
> proto.SetExtension(m, extpb.E_RepeatedMessage, &extpb.Bar{})
>
> v1 := proto.GetExtension(m, extpb.E_SingularInt32).(int32)
> v2 := proto.GetExtension(m, extpb.E_RepeatedString).([][]byte)
> v3 := proto.GetExtension(m, extpb.E_RepeatedMessage).(*extpb.Bar)
> ```